# How to extend the .NET TestClass

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to extend the .NET `TestClass`. I found out that I need to extend the following abstract classes: `TestClassExtensionAttribute` and `TestExtensionExecution`. `TestExtensionExecution` also requires me to implement an `ITestMethodInvoker`. I have done the following but when I run a test method none of my breakpoints are being hit (neither in the test nor the extensions), meaning the test class never gets to my extension and obviously fails at an earlier point. **Could somebody point me at what I am missing or at a working example for how to extend the** `TestClass`?

Extension:

```
class CoreTestClass : TestClassExtensionAttribute
{
    public override Uri ExtensionId
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override TestExtensionExecution GetExecution()
    {
        return new TestCore();
    }
}

class TestCore: TestExtensionExecution
{
    public override ITestMethodInvoker CreateTestMethodInvoker(TestMethodInvokerContext context)
    {
        return new AnalysisTestMethodInvoker();
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public override void Initialize(TestExecution execution)
    {
        execution.OnTestStopping += execution_OnTestStopping;
    }

    void execution_OnTestStopping(object sender, OnTestStoppingEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class AnalysisTestMethodInvoker : ITestMethodInvoker
{
    public TestMethodInvokerResult Invoke(params object[] parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[CoreTestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {
        // Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.", result.ViewBag.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered the 4th issue mentioned [here](http://www.digitaltapestry.net/blog/extending-mstest) ?

Comment: I haven't seen this article so far. I will look at it and maybe it will provide me with a solution. If I find one I will post it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It might looks stupid, but isn't it due to a missing "public" before the extension class declaration?!!!

Comment: Have you had any luck with the custom execution extension already? I'm trying to do the same but like in your question no breakpoints are hit.

Comment: I dropped this effort after I couldn't get this to work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This MSDN article describes how to implement `TestClassExtensionAttribute`: [Extending the Visual Studio unit test type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-1.aspx)

Related question: [Is defining TestMethod's in test base classes not supported by MsTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523826/is-defining-testmethods-in-test-base-classes-not-supported-by-mstest)

Depending on what you are tyring to accomplish you can use a standard abstract class marked with `[TestClass]`. `TestClassAttribute` will be inherited by derived types, however derived types must also be marked with `[TestClass]` for use with `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]`.

See [Using a base class for your unit testing classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/densto/archive/2008/05/16/using-a-base-class-for-your-unit-test-classes.aspx).